# PLEASE UNCAP USER NAMES ON THE PROFILE PAGES

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, design

> [image]

I mean, eh, I'd like the names not to be in all caps, my name is "nicael", not "NICAEL", right? Pretty please?

Comment: Ah, thanks for adressing that, I didn't dare to since I felt it's not too important. But it is indeed a bit annoying.

Comment: By the way, here's the more general discussion on the main meta (since we're not the only site that does this): http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/244847/162011.

Comment: I notice so many little things on this site, but that has never been one of them. It never even occurred to me or bothered me!

Comment: +1, NOT ONLY FOR THE IMPORTANCE OF THE REQUEST, BUT ALSO FOR WRITINE THE TITLE IN ALL CAPS. I THINK THAT ALL TEXT SHOULD BE NOW ALL-CAPS ON THE SITES THAT HAVE THIS "FEATURE" _/sarcasm_

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is being fixed now. Stand by.

And, done!

Comment: Great. Wonderful!